# URL Rewriting for php files in web.config

Tags: php, url-rewriting, web-config

I have some problem here ,I've checked all the answers from another post here but I encountered 500 error , or nothing happen .

The problem is:

Consider that I have a website like : `flan.com`

So, I have a dynamic URL like:

`flan.com/index.php?page=25` or 
`flan.com/news.php?news=aqweqwr546`

Note that this value "aqweqwr546" is dynamic and can be number or alphabetic or both of them.

I need something like this:

For the first one : `flan.com/page/a title shown here`

For the second one : `flan.com/news/a title shown here`

or something like this that is user friendly URL!

Please help me.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite your urls like this...

```
RewriteEngine On
#For home page. i.e. index.php
RewriteRule ^page/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]

#For news page i.e news.php
RewriteRule ^news/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ news.php?news=$1 [L]
```

`web.config` like this..

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite to index.php">
      <match url="^page/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$"/>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?page={R:1}/>
    </rule>
    <rule name="Rewrite to news.php">
      <match url="^news/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$"/>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="news.php?news={R:1}/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: for more see here https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Answer (score 0):

Create or edit the `.htaccess` file in the root of your website, and put this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule /(.*)/$ news.php?news=$1
```

This will give you an url that looks like this:

```
flan.com/aqweqwr546/
```

Or this:

```
RewriteRule /(.*)/(.*)/$ $1.php?news=$2
```

Will give you this:

```
flan.com/news/aqweqwr546/
```

Comment: sorry I have web.config instead of .htaccess because the server is running in windows, how can be in web.config ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with web.config. But, according to [this tool](http://cbsa.com.br/tools/online-convert-htaccess-to-web-config.aspx), something like this: `<rule name="rule 1N"><match url="/(.*)/$"  /><action type="Rewrite" url="/news.php?news={R:1}"  /></rule>`

Comment: after I add this , nothing happen to website